# How to get RowsAffected in Go-Gorm's Association Mode

Tags: mysql, go, go-gorm

I insert a relation by the following code:

```golang
db.Where(exercise).FirstOrCreate(&exercise).Model(&User{ID: userID}).Association("Exercises").Append(&exercise)
```

Corresponding SQL printed by debug console to the code is:

```
INSERT INTO `user_exercise` (`user_id`,`exercise_id`) SELECT 1,1 FROM DUAL WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM `user_exercise` WHERE `user_id` = 1 AND `exercise_id` = 1)
```

I want know if there are new record created in `user_exercise`, but due to the generated SQL, if a relation in `user_exercise` already exists, it won't insert and produce no error.

Go-Gorm's `Association` object doesn't have a `RowsAffected` attribute, so I can't get `RowsAffected` from the query to confirm if a new record is created.

Though I can get `RowsAffected` from the first `db` object, like

```
db.Where(exercise).FirstOrCreate(&exercise).Model(&User{ID: userID}).Association("Exercises").Append(&exercise)
if db.RowsAffected == 1 {
    // do something
}
```

I wonder since the db is shared by all queries, if another query executed at the same time and affected rows > 0, is it safe to get `RowsAffected`  from the global `db` object?

Comment: If you found an answer to your question (I see your own answer deleted by yourself below), why not post it and accept it? This could help others looking for similar information

Comment: @EliBendersky I found my answer is wrong after a test. So I delete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the `user_execise` table has an unique constraint (user_id, exercise_id) the insert should return an error if you try to do it to an already created record. (Exactly what you want)
So just do something like this...

```golang
db.Where(exercise).FirstOrCreate(&exercise)
ue := struct {
  UserID uint
  ExerciseID uint
}{
  UserID: userID,
  ExerciseID exercise.ID
}
if err := db.Table("user_exercise").Create(&ue).Error; err != nil {
  // will enter here if it wasn't created
}
```

If it doesn't returns an Error means that a new record was created

Comment: `Append` returns an `Association` object and it doesn't have a `RowsAffected `

Comment: @LiJinyao Yeah, you're right, I just improved my answer =D